# How do I add or edit the texts in a billing document form/template?

Tags: sapscript

I was trying to edit a billing document template/form. I need to rename and add some fields like add a VAT field, currency field, and so on.

I tried using SE71 but I can't seem to see the fields I'm trying to edit/add.

The details I only have is program name, form name, and billing document number. What TCode I should use to edit it?

Image below is the representation of sample invoice document. I was able to check the invoice using vf03 but I don't know how to edit it using se71.

I need to replace the SIC NO with different text, and need to add an expiration date in the said document
[image]

Comment: the requirement is a bit unclear. Do you want to change the print form itself or only the printout created for a single document? The first means changing the SAPScript form in SE71 and maybe the print program as well, the latter means just changing either some standard text (transaction SO10) or some fields in the document that is printed.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek I want to change the template of the billing document so whenever I print I'm seeing the new template.

Comment: Then you would need to change the SAPScript form in SE71 in your development system. But good old SAPScript is not exactly easy to maintain. You have a print program that calls different elements of the form at different times, exposing the variables of the print program to the form. Quite often you need to either know the print programs existing data structures or even create new ones to implement requirements. I think it's a bit too involved to explain in a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek meaning, I can't just easily edit the text elements in the said form but instead I should edit the program that prints the form? Saying I have to add a currency (GBP for UK market and EURO for Ireland market) text in a text element "Total Net Value", I have to add it in an ABAP program instead of adding it on the SAP Form? thanks

Comment: Depends on the form and program. SAPScript print programs are tightly coupled, and some information is in the form itself, some comes from data structures, some may be generated in the print program. A header text will likely be in the form itself, but the currency will be stored in a data structure coming from the print program.

Comment: `meaning, I can't just easily edit the text elements in the said form but instead I should edit the program that prints the form?` yes, it's exactly what Dirk means, you are in a big sh.. with the SapScript